How to add incremental number between every few lines in VIM
I have a text file
a, b
c, d
e, f
g, h
i, j
etc

I need the following file using VIM at every N line. Here, I use N=2
a, b
c, d
1
e, f
g, h
2
i, j
etc

Is there any way in VIM?

What did you try?

yes, there is a way in vim to do that. But as romainl stated, where are you stuck? What are you missing? If you don't have any knowledge of vim, there are other solutions which may be more suited

Yes. You can use Vim's macro function.
First, insert the number 1 above the starting line.
Then record the macro as the following commands
qiyy2jp<ctrl>aq

q starts the macro recording;
i indicates the macro's name. It can be replaced with any letter;
yy copies the current line, where the ordinal number is;
2j: 2 is the N you want and j move to the next ordinal number's line;
p pastes the previous ordinal number's line;
<ctrl>a increase the ordinal number;
q: ends the recording.

Then place the cursor on the first ordinal number's line and use @i to play the recorded macro. Use M@i to play it M times.
